# データベースの設計について

Tags: mysql, データベース設計

データベースの設計で悩んでいます。

例えばユーザー情報用のデータベースを作るとします。

---

#### users

- id
- name

---

これに性別を持たせるときは

---

#### users

- id
- name
- sex_id

#### sexes

- id
- name

---

これでよいと思うのですが、例えばグループを持たせたいときにすごく悩んでしまいます。

---

#### users

- id
- name
- group_id

#### groups

- id
- name

---

こうしてしまうと、将来複数のグループを持たせたいとなった時に融通がきかなくなると思います。
なので

---

#### users

- id
- name

#### groups_users

- id
- user_id
- group_id

#### groups

- id
- name

---

このように中間テーブルを挟むことになると思うのですが、将来必要になるかどうかわからないものを最初からこのように設計しても問題ありませんか?
必要になってから工事するくらいなら・・・と思ってしまうのですが。

みなさんはどうしてますか?
失敗談などもあれば是非教えて下さい。

Comment: 開発初期から、将来の拡張を考慮して、柔軟な設計にするのは良いことだと思います。
使わなかったとしても、理解し難い作りでは無いと思います。

Comment: 書き忘れましたが、JSONの配列でぶっ込んでたのは見たことあります。

Comment: `sexes`を別のテーブルに入れるのはメリットがなくて、パフォーマンスへの影響もあります。`users`のテーブルに`sex ENUM('F','M') NOT NULL`を追加したほうが良いと思います。

Answer (score 1):

一言にグループと言っても
単一所属グループの場合、複数所属グループの場合、階層型グループの場合。
複数グループに所属して、その中で優先グループをもつ場合もあります。
どれを想定するかで適切な設計が決まります。

今迷っているのは将来の拡張性ではなく、まだグループの要件が詰めきれていないからではないでしょうか。
もしそうなら、決定まで設計は待った方がいい気がします。

Answer (score 1):

「将来を見据えた設計をすべし」とも言われますし「将来を見越しすぎるのは無駄」とも言われます。正解はありません。

こういう状況で様々な要素を判断してよりベターな選択ができるのが設計者のスキルそのものです。

Answer (score 0):

フレームワーク的なアプローチで考えてみますね。
user.groupでドバーっとあちこち書きまくったやつを、
user.groupsにしたらレコードインスタンスだったものが配列になるので大変です。
それなら最初から「常に配列だけど現状１件しか帰ってこないよ」の方が気が楽です。

しかしその場合でもuser.groups.firstとか書いちゃったら意味がありません。

以上のことから
「groupsが複数あること前提で設計する（＝複数きた時の挙動が定義できる）」
かどうかが判断材料としています。現時点で定義できないなら書くよりも
「そのときは、変更コストかかりますからね？」と釘刺したほうがストレスなく済みますよ。　：）